# How is the presentation of navigation link in pagination get build?

Tags: html, css, sql, pagination

I am looking into how to do a simple pagination in html and I think I am missing something.
I figured how to do the `LIMIT` using the current page number and the maximum no of rows per page.
Also I found some tutorials on how to display the links which is via css. E.g.

```
<ul id="mystyle">  
<li class="previous">«Previous</li>  
<li class="active">1</li>  
<li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=5">5</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>  
<li class="next"><a href="?page=2">Next »</a></li>  
</ul>
```

But I am confused on the display of the links that the user presses to select among pages. When the user views the first batch of rows, he should not be able to see a `Previous` because there is no previous at this point (I mean before page 1 there is no previous).
So for the last batch he should not be able to see a `Next` (at least being a hyperlink) since there is no `Next` after the last page. But I am confused on how to determine that.
The only way I can think of is if I do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` so as to have the total size of the result set I am paging. But doesn't this defeat the purpose of paging performance wise. I have experienced in huge result sets the `SELECT COUNT(*)` to take significant amount of time (especially if we have joins-I mean besides the amount of data).
I need help in understanding how to build the algorithm and the subtleties that confuse me.

Comment: I don't know what your front end is being built on top of, but I generally do this type of stuff on the server side.

Comment: @masedesign:Server side solution is what I am looking into building

Comment: It's really tough to say without looking at what's returning to the front end. Potentially, there is a pretty simple JavaScript solution if your page links are consistent (based on page number only) and you can set a variable to the total number of pages and the current page.

Comment: @masedesign:Why does this depend on the return?The page is build on the server. The number of links is fixed. E.g. 10

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, this is without seeing your server side code or knowing anything about your application but potentially, this jQuery solution could get you started. Again, it's not the way I would handle it.

```
if ($('li.active').text() === '1') {
    $('li.previous').hide();
}

if ($('li.next').prev('li').hasClass('active')) {
    $('li.next').hide();
}
```

This will hide your Previous/Next buttons when it should.

Comment: `$('li.next').prev('li').hasClass('active')` What's the idea here?I don't follow

Comment: If the last page is active, then there is no next page, so it hides the next page link. In your example, if you were on page 7, the next button would be hidden.

Comment: :This is wrong or I am missing the point.If the last *link*  from the navigation links is active that does not mean that the last page is active since we could have more available in the result set.So we come to the original question using `SELECT COUNT *`.Otherwise how do we know when it is the last page?

Comment: That is correct, if you are interested in a pagination where the scope is outside of what is displayed or where you don't always show the last page (like some choose to do) you will have to count the number of page.